# Excluding child elements from parent's css

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div called 'daddy' which contains two other divs, the parent div has a particular css animation which makes it blink every 1 second. However I'm attempting to make it so that this css animation only works on the 'daddy' element rather than the child elements.

**My reason** for this is to keep all the elements together because I'd like the child elements to follow the parent and be in the same position wherever it goes.

***JSFiddle:*** http://jsfiddle.net/qsn1b445/1/

**HTML**

```
 <div id="daddy">ok
    <div id="son"> I know my ABC's!</div>
    <div id="daughter"> sure you do</div>
</div>
```

I've tried using the :not() method in both css and javascript but to no avail. I'd greatly appreciate if anyone can think of an effective method to help with this issue, thanks!

Comment: So tonight we're gonna party like it's 1999!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you just want to blink the 'ok' text. How about creating another 'div' element under the parent element, just for that piece of text? Then you can blink that specific 'div' child.

Comment: I see, but wouldn't that prevent the elements from being together?

Comment: Which elements? What's the problem with that?

Comment: wait, I see what you mean (I'm a bit slow this morning xD), thank you Mr. Phang :)